# Масштабируемый TextView

Tags: android, textview

Помогите пожалуйста настроить масштабирование TextView.

Всё, что касается параметров app:autoSizeTextType="uniform" и android:breakStrategy="simple" я перепробовал. Масштаб меняется, но не для всех случаев. Мне нужно, чтобы масштабирование текста работало для слов любой длины, но если я вставляю в TextView длинное слово, то android начинает глупые переносы слов на новую строку.

Например:
автоматизац
ия

Пример моего кода:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Автоматизация"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="2sp"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="60sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="1sp"
    android:breakStrategy="simple"
    android:maxLines="10"
    />
```

Как я понял, если android видит, что ему можно разместить текст на 10 линий - android:maxLines="10", то он будет увеличивать масштаб текста до самого большого app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="60sp", и ему без разницы, что слово перенеслось на новую строку. Почему android не делает выбор в пользу размера слова, чтобы оно вошло в строку без переносов? Было бы удобно, если автомасштабирование чувствовало, что пора прекратить увеличивать размер текста, так как слово сейчас начнет переносится на новую строку и остановилось на размере например 50sp.

Параметр android:hyphenationFrequency="full" тоже не срабатывает. По сути данный параметр должен переносить слова на новую строку по слогам, но он не работает даже на английском тексте.

Моё TextView в разных случаях может показывать разное количество текста, от одного слова до абзаца, поэтому я указал android:maxLines="10"

Comment: Вряд ли возможно сделать описанное вами идеально. Если бы это было просто - оно бы уже было сделано. Скорее всего, чтобы было прямо хорошо - надо машинное обучение подключать и обучать модель на миллионах примеров того как надо. Я бы на вашем месте не стал бы тратить время на попытки оптимизации описанного вами.

Comment: Я думаю, что можно попробовать программно пробегаться по TextView и проверять переносилось ли какое либо слово и если переносилось, то программно задавать уменьшение максимального размера через метод textView.setAutoSizeTextTypeUniformWithConfiguration(10, 50, 1, TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP);
Вот только пока не могу понять, как программно определить, что слово было перенесено на новую строку. Может у вас есть какие либо идеи?

Comment: Таким никогда не занимался, помочь ничем не смогу(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение самостоятельно. Возможно для кого-то будет полезно.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView;
float sizeWidthTextView;
int textMaxAutoSize = 50;
StringBuilder singleWordBuilder = new StringBuilder();

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSize);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Определяем ширину экрана в пикселях
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int widthDisplay = size.x;
    textView.setTextSize(textMaxAutoSize);

    //Определяем ширину TextView в пикселях
    sizeWidthTextView = textView.getLayoutParams().width;

    //Если ширина TextView задана как wrap_content либо match_parent, то будут возвращены значения -1 и -2
    //нас это не устраивает и мы присваиваем переменной ширину всего дисплея.
    if(sizeWidthTextView == -1 || sizeWidthTextView == -2) {
        sizeWidthTextView = widthDisplay;
    }

    //Считаем длину каждого слова в пикселях и уменьшаем размер шрифта так, чтобы слово вмещалось в ширину TextView
    for(int i = 0; i < textView.getText().length(); i++) {
        if (textView.getText().charAt(i) != ' ') {
            singleWordBuilder.append(textView.getText().charAt(i));
            String singleWord = String.valueOf(singleWordBuilder);
            float sizeWord = textView.getPaint().measureText(singleWord);
            //Уменьшаем максимальный размер шрифта до тех пор пока слово не вместится в ширину TextView
            while (sizeWidthTextView  < sizeWord) {
                textMaxAutoSize--;
                textView.setTextSize(textMaxAutoSize);
                sizeWord = textView.getPaint().measureText(singleWord);
            }
        } else {
            singleWordBuilder.setLength(0);
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewSize"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:breakStrategy="simple"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:text="Авто авто Автоматизационный авто"/>
```